# Jquery code no longer works with newer version 2.1.4 was on 1.11.0

Tags: jquery

**I upgraded from Jquery 1.11.0 --> 2.1.4  now this code does not work**

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function () {
   $(this).closest('tr').find('input:checkbox').removeProp('checked');
   $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/removeProp/):

> Note: **Do not use this method to remove native properties such as
> checked**, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property
> completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use
> .prop() to set these properties to false instead.

Change your code to

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function () {
     $(this).closest('tr').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
     $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Side note 1: I've never seen any valid reason to use `removeProp`. If you use it elsewhere, you probably should have another look at that part too.

Side note 2: It looks like you're emulating radio buttons with check boxes. This might be a little disturbing to your users.

Comment: good to know, finding code with google search and just being excited that it "works" without knowing every method and property is clearly dangerous ,  ty

Comment: Yes they were radio buttons originally, but then they (business folks) wanted ability to reset radio buttons so none were selected independent of each row.   So then it was either have another column to reset or a completely bad experience of trying to click on a radio button that is selected to have javascript then deselect it....